# Algolia: search for multiples values in each fields with AND clause

Tags: javascript, algolia

I would like know if i can query different values in each field 
returning values that only match with the search like AND condition. I tried use search in multpile indexes, but it return values like OR condition.

Example:

**my index contains:**

```js
[
 {
  firstName: 'Alisson',
  lastName: 'Oliveira',
 },
 {
  firstName: 'Alex',
  lastName: 'Oliver',
 },
{
  firstName: 'Daniel',
  lastName: 'Costa',
 }
]
```

**my query would be:**

```js
index.search(query: { firstName: 'Al', lastName: 'Oliv' })
```

**the response espected:**

```js
[
 {
  firstName: 'Alisson',
  lastName: 'Oliveira',
 },
 {
  firstName: 'Alex',
  lastName: 'Oliver',
 }
]
```

Someone know if is possible in the algolia?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your example it sounds like your end-user would type the query: `"Al Oliv"` and you would expect the two records shown above to return.

To do this, you would change the default settings from `prefixLast` to `prefixAll`.  You can do this in the Dashboard: 
[image]

By default Algolia only uses the last word as a prefix. If you make the change above the query will return the expected results:
[image]